# Is proportional relationship also a linear relationship?

Tags: linear-algebra

I understand that a proportional relationship is $y=mx$ and a linear relationship is $y=mx+b$.

But if a line crosses $(0,0)$, is it fair to say it is both proportional and linear assuming constant rate of change?

Comment: Yes, since $y = mx$ is just a special case of $y = mx + b$ for $b = 0$. An alternative naming convention uses *linear* for $y = mx$ and *affine* for $y = mx + b$.

Answer (score 2):

Recall that elements $x_1,\dots,x_n$ of a vector space over a field are **linearly dependent** if there are not all zero coefficients $k_1,\dots,k_n$ such that $k_1x_1+\dots +k_nx_n=0$.
A relation of the form $y=mx$ is a linear dependence relation: actually, if you have only **two** elements, then proportionality $y=mx$ and linear dependence of $y,\,x$ ($m_1y+m_2x=0$ where $m_1\ne0$ or $m_2\ne0$) are the same thing.

On the other band, a relation of the form $y=mx+b$ is said to be an **affine relation**. This means that any linear dependence relation is affine (set $b=0$), but not every affine relation is linear (choose $b\ne0$).

**Edit**: Of course, a line through the origin express a linear dependence between its points.

Answer (score 2):

There is another view to the linearity problem. Let us suppose that the relation $f$ is linear and $x$ is the input whereas $y=f(x)$ is the output. Now, $f$ is a linear relation if it follows **superposition theorem**.

Let us say if $x_1$ is input to the relation $f$ we write the output as:
$$x_1\rightarrow y_1=f(x_1)$$
Similarly if $x_2$ is input to the relation $f$ we write the output as:
$$x_2\rightarrow y_2=f(x_2)$$
Now the superposition theorem states that, another input which is a linear combination of both the inputs $x_1$ and $x_2$ should produce the same linear combination of the ouput $y_1$ and $y_2$:

$$\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2\rightarrow\alpha y_1+ \beta y_2=\alpha f(x_1)+\beta f(x_2)$$
If you can prove this, then the relation is linear.
Now let us check the linearity of $y=mx$ :
$$x_1 \rightarrow y_1 = mx_1$$
$$x_2 \rightarrow y_2 = mx_2$$
If we calculate the output for $\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2$ we get:
$$\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2 \rightarrow f(\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2)=m(\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2)$$
$$m(\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2)=m \alpha x_1+ m \beta x_2 =\alpha y_1+ \beta y_2$$
So $$\alpha x_1+ \beta x_2 \rightarrow \alpha y_1+ \beta y_2$$
So the relation is linear.

If you check for $y=mx+b$

$$x_1 \rightarrow y_1 = f(x_1) = mx_1+b$$
$$x_2 \rightarrow y_2 = f(x_1) = mx_2+b$$
Now calculate for $\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2$
$$\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2 \rightarrow f(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) =m(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2)+b$$
But if you calculate $\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2$ you will get:
$$\alpha y_1 + \beta y_2=\alpha (mx_1+b) + \beta (mx_2 +b) \ne m(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2)+b$$
So it is not linear. Hope this helps ...